# How to transform linebreaks inside MySQL column data into \n?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, line-breaks

The column data is fed by a textarea html element in the web page ; so the user can enter linebreaks within it. When I put the column data inside an excel file then excel does not recognize the linebreak ( there is a "?" at the end of the first line ). So how to make it recognizable by excel ?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem a little earlier, The easiest solution (Not the best, but couldn't think of anything else) is to use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

The only way i found to get this to work correctly, was to replace `\n` with `\n\r`. An example of this would be

```
<?php
    str_replace("\n", "\n\r", $input_text);
?>
```

It is possible to do this while inserting into the database, or while reading from the database, However it does present a problem that if it already has `\n\r`, it'll then appear like `\n\r\r`